# Can a matrix have eigenvalue with infinite multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose we have matrix of the form

$$
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      a & -1 \\
    0 & a  \\     
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

and we would like to analyze its diagonalizability.

By taking the characteristic equation we quickly find $a^2 = 0$. In this case, can we say that this matrix has eigenvalue of 0 with infinite multiplicity?

Comment: The characteristic equation is $x \mapsto (x-a)^2$ which shows that $a$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity two. Where do you get the infinite from?

Comment: And no, an eigenvalue is a zero of a polynomial, so it can only have finite multiplicity.

Comment: How did you decide that $a^2 = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're computing the determinant of $A$, which is not the characteristic polynomial. The characteristic polynomial is rather
$$
\det(A-XI)=\det\begin{bmatrix}a-X&-1\\0&a-X\end{bmatrix}=(a-X)^2
$$
which has one root (equal to $a$) with multiplicity $2$.

The matrix is not diagonalizable, because
$$
A-aI=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. This is a polynomial equation in $a$ of degree $2$, so that if there is only one $a\in\mathbb R$ with $a^2=0$ (and this is the case: any $a\neq 0$ will have $a^2>0$), then this $a$ will be a double root, that is, a root of multiplicity $2$.

In the end, you can never have an eigenvalue of multiplicity greater than $n$ for an $n\times n$ matrix, because the characteristic equation of an $n\times n$ matrix is *always* a polynomial equation of degree $n$.